# Nested output by group in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection like this.

```
let Movies= [
{year: '2000', language: 'English', genre: 'Romance' , name: 'A beautiful day'},
{year: '2000', language: 'English', genre: 'Action' , name: 'A Dangerous day'},
{year: '2000', language: 'French', genre: 'Romance' , name: 'someromancename'},
{year: '2000', language: 'French', genre: 'Action' , name: 'someactionname'},]
```

I need to get a output in group format which may look something like this:

```
{
"2000" : {
            "English": {
                        "Romance": [{
                                    "name":"A beautiful day"
                                     //other fields
                                    }]
                        "Action": [{
                                    "name":"A dangerous day"
                                    }]
                        },
            "French": {
                        "Romance": [{
                                    "name":"Some Romance Name"
                                    }]
                        "Action": [{
                                    "name":"Some Action Name"
                                    }]
                        },
        }
```

}

I have tried using aggregation but not able to get the exact query as I am new to MongoDB. This is what I tried to do but the expected result is not achieved.

```
db.getCollection('Movies').aggregate([
{$group: {_id: {"year" : "$year",
            "language": "$language" , 
            "genre": "$genre" , 
            
            },
       "movies": {"$push": "$$ROOT"}
      } 
  },
  {$group: {_id: "$_id.year",
            "movies": {"$push": {
                "language": "$_id.language",
                "genre": "$_id.genre" , 
                "movies": "$movies"
                }}     
  }
  },

  ])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try,

- `$group` by `year, language and genre`, and make array of movies name in `movies`
- `$group` by `year and language` and make array of with genre in k and v format
- `$group` by `year` and make array of language after converting above genre array to object using $arrayToObject
- convert language array to object using `$arrayToObject`, convert year with `languages` object to object using `$arrayToObject` and replace that object to root using `$replaceRoot`

```
db.getCollection('Movies').aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "year": "$year",
        "language": "$language",
        "genre": "$genre"
      },
      "movies": { "$push": { name: "$name" } }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        year: "$_id.year",
        language: "$_id.language"
      },
      "movies": {
        "$push": {
          k: "$_id.genre",
          v: "$movies"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.year",
      movies: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.language",
          v: { $arrayToObject: "$movies" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: [[
            {
              k: "$_id",
              v: { $arrayToObject: "$movies" }
            }
        ]]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qTOqbIqHqOm)